# Plaid API implementation with Java

Tags: java, spring, maven, plaid

I want to develop a web application(Java, JSP and JS) with Plaid to pull all Bank transactions. I follwed the following links

https://github.com/plaid/plaid-java

From the above repository i used the following in Maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.plaid</groupId>
  <artifactId>plaid-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and added the following code

```
PlaidClient plaidClient = PlaidClient.newBuilder()
  .clientIdAndSecret("your_client_id", "your_secret")
  .publicKey("your_public_key") // optional. only needed to call endpoints that require a public key
  .sandboxBaseUrl() // or equivalent, depending on which environment you're calling into
  .build();
```

and changed `Client_Id`, `Secret_Key` and `Public_Key`. but it throws the following exception. i asked Plaid but there is no useful response from Plaid support.

> Sep 18, 2017 7:12:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mysample] in context
>   with path [/mysample] threw exception [Handler processing failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(Lcom/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory;)Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;]
>   with root cause java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(Lcom/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory;)Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
>   at
>   com.plaid.client.PlaidClient$Builder.buildGson(PlaidClient.java:155)
>   at com.plaid.client.PlaidClient$Builder.build(PlaidClient.java:145) at
>   com.mysample.common.controller.MobileController.loginTz(MobileController.java:593)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   com.mysample.security.filter.ValidationFilter.doFilter(ValidationFilter.java:359)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   com.mysample.security.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:167)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I can't even start my development in Plaid please help

Thanks in Advance

Nova

Answer (score 0):

Possible incorrect dependencies and probably you are using older dependency that is overriding actual one needed